# Combine controller names in URL (rails routes)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have a Real Estate site and i like to order the url of each publication.

The publication controller have this relation:

type_id (House for sell, House for rent, etc..)
country_id (USA, Italia, Argentina, etc.)
state_id (New York, Roma, Buenos Aires, etc.)

The path to each publication i want to be like this:

http://www.domain.com/publication/house-for-sale/usa/new-york/24-street-therestofaddress

Exist any way to do this in routes.conf ?

I use friendly_id gem and i like to works without static routes.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I use friendly_id gem and i like to works without static routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [static segments](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#static-segments):

```
match 'publication/:type/:country/:state/:id' => 'publications#show'
```

Then in your controller, you'd have access to all these parameters. For example, consider the url http://www.domain.com/publication/house-for-sale/usa/new-york/24-street-therestofaddress which the controller action would process as:

```
class PublicationController < ApplicationController
  def show
    params[:type]     # "house-for-sale"
    params[:country]  # "usa"
    params[:state]    # "new-york"
    params[:id]       # 24
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, i will try ! but i like to this was an automatic route genrated!

Comment: I don't think there is an automatic nested resources solution that maps to the url you want.